# Facebook ios sdk Graph request allows only one field as parameter

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I'm developing an app which requires facebook login, and user details. However, the same code that I used in previous apps for fb login doesn't work, and I need to make separate graph requests for each field like name, email, picture, etc.

Basically, whenever I try to do the following:

```
connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters:["fields":"email, name, picture"])) { httpResponse, result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    guard let userInfo = response.dictionaryValue else {
                        return
                    }
                    userDict["email"] = userInfo["email"]! as Any
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(userDict["email"], forKey: userKeys.email)
                case .failed(let error):
                    print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
                }
            }
```

I get this error:

```
Graph Request Failed: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Syntax error "Expected end of string instead of "%"." at character 5: email%2C%20name%2C%20picture, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 2500;
        "fbtrace_id" = "FIc1yiUL+1z";
        message = "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"%\".\" at character 5: email%2C%20name%2C%20picture";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
```

And a similar error when I do:

```
connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters:["fields":"picture.type(large)"]))
```

However, it doesn't give an error when I put in a single field as a parameter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to that question too, been having the same issue since i update my pods last night. I had other issues with the FB Login and found another article that was explaining there are issues with the SDK 4.39.0, maybe this is related to the same problem... My code was working and is no longer working with the pod update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too got the same error when trying with the latest release. I suggest you to downgrade to the previous version. For me below versions are working fine:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.0' 
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.0'
```

After that run

`pod deintegrate`

`pod install`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()
    loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "user_photos" ,"user_videos"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {

        } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
            print("Cancelled")
        } else {               
            let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "email, id, name"])
            graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if ((error) != nil) {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                } else {
                    var userName:String?
                    var userID:String?
                    var userIEmail:String? = ""
                    if let user : NSString = (result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name") as? NSString {
                        userName = "\(user)"
                    }
                    if let id : NSString = (result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id") as? NSString {
                        userID = id as String
                        if userID == UserDefaultsHelper.username{
                            self.ClearUserData = false
                        }
                    }
                    if let email : NSString = (result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email") as? NSString {
                        userIEmail = email as String
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, gives the same error: "Expected end of string instead of "%"." at character 5: email%2C%20id%2C%20name"